# What is faster than a relay?

Tags: relay, signal, 555, generator

I need to find something that is faster than a relay.

What I'm trying to build is an electrosurgical generator for acollege project.
I want to accomplish something like this:

[image: graph]

This was the reference I was given to work with.

My idea is to use a simpler signal generator (I'll use a XR2206 or an AD9833 since the frequencies I plan to work with are 500 to 600 kHz) that gives me a sine signal; using a LM555 establish a frequency that activates a *sort of relay* for the signals pass and stop, just like in that graph, after that I need to amplify it (I don't knoe how) to achieve the voltage and amperage that I need.

The thing is, I need to turn it on and off really fast, but I can't seem to find anything that works at such speed.

Any recommendations are welcome, I'm new when it comes to making circuits.

Comment: The kV is probably a bit of an issue. Maybe you should create the waveform you want in the first place.

Comment: is this a trigger pulse? if so you may use  square wave from signal generator and  RC  circuit. something like [this](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/rc-rc43.gif)

Comment: Do you want to gate the high voltage signal directly, or gate the low voltage signal out of the sine circuit than then amplify the gated wafeform?

Comment: i want to obtain the low voltage signal first then amplify it once gated.

Comment: Here's my idea of how to botain that signal (not taking into account the amplitud or frecuency, just the idea) https://imgur.com/a/enlUWZC

Comment: _"the frequencies i plan to work with are 500khz to 600khz"_ does that just mean 'somewhere between' 500kHz and 600kHz, or do you have to generate  specific frequencies?

Comment: _"i want to obtain the low voltage signal first then amplify it once gated."_ - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer

Comment: Do you really need to generate a signal with such high amplitude? 4 kilovolts? If so, I think you need to keep that in mind from the start. I don't think it is wise to plan to generate the signal at 5 volts and then amplify it up to 4 kilovolts with an amplifier. I think you might need to use an autotransformer or maybe an ignition coil from a car. I am not really an expert on high voltage techniques.

Comment: Where is the signal going to? Since it looks like a damped sinusoid, maybe you can just send a pulse to the primary of an ignition coil and put some capacitors  on the secondary to let it oscillate like that (more or less).

Comment: yes, is somewhere between those frequencies, is not specific and should be variable.

As for the 4kv, i don't need to achieve those 4kv, a low voltage should be enough (at least i was told to amplify it to 30v, 2A, it's a simple project and the teacher recognises it might be difficult to students)

Comment: The signal is (in theory) applied to a patient, i need those high frequencies, with on and off moments in order just to generate heat and cut/cuagulate the skin (The plan is to test it on meat) https://www.giejournal.org/article/S0016-5107(13)01780-X/fulltext#:~:text=Electrosurgical%20generator%20units%20(ESUs)%20facilitate,into%20thermal%20energy%20within%20tissue.

So the best is to create a pulses with a coil? will those give me the 600khz?

Comment: No the ignition coil was for high voltage. If it is only 30 V you probably don't need anything like an ignition coil. Probably just a microcontroller switching a MOSFET H-bridge. Something like that.

Comment: i'm sorry but am kinda confused how can i set up an h-bridge in order to make it my activation and deactivation device to create the signal

Comment: Maybe read about class D amplifiers.

Comment: have you considered a vacuum tube?

Comment: Solid state relay is a faster choice.

Answer (score 1):

The reference waveform is very similar to infinitesimally narrow pulses (Dirac delta function) repeated at 6.7kHz rate, filtered by a damped 2nd order filter (e.g. LC tank).

The way I'd go about building such a circuit would be to create narrow pulses of say ~100V amplitude, form them into the desired decaying waveform using a relatively low impedance LC network, and amplify them using a ferrite core step-up transformer. The transformer could be a computer CRT flyback transformer probably, but it'd need to be one from a later multiscan model. It'd not be most efficient in terms of power transfer, but it'd do the job.

The biggest question that you absolutely need to know the answer to: what is the load connected to this high voltage output? By "load" I mean an electrical circuit equivalent to whatever the actual load would be. E.g. saying "it connects to tissue" or somesuch is not an adequate description. When designing electrocautery tools, it is assumed that the load is a passive circuit with certain lumped elements. This model of a load will largely drive the design.

As for "something faster than a relay": these pulses could be probably driven with a reed relay connected to an equivalent of an automotive ignition coil, but it wouldn't be practical. Reed relays can self-resonate mechanically at frequencies between 1-10kHz, so you could select one with a resonance close enough to 6.66kHz. This would be more of a "hey, yes, I can use a relay" demonstration rather than a long-term viable circuit. The relay would not last very long used like that.

Comment: JOOI, would using a ring counter to activate several reed relays be a sensible measure to avoid the self-resonance?

Comment: @AndrewMorton The resonance's purpose is to make the relays mechanically as fast as possible. They switch slower when off-resonance. And you don't want the relays to be on for very long, since that wastes power and can saturate the inductor. If the relay performance is acceptable without using mechanical resonance, then the ring counter will do the trick.